# Cannot delete '?' character

Tags: python, pandas

I can't delete '?' character from my data frame. First I wanted to use na_values parameter in pd.read_csv method but it didn't work - I can't see any NaN. Next I wanted to use replace method but:

```
data['Workclass'].value_counts()

 Private             22696
 Self-emp-not-inc     2541
 Local-gov            2093
 ?                    1836
 State-gov            1297
 Self-emp-inc         1116
 Federal-gov           960
 Without-pay            14
 Never-worked            7
Name: Workclass, dtype: int64

data.isin(['?']).sum()

Age                          0
Workclass                    0
Final weight                 0
Education                    0
Education number of years    0
Marital status               0
Occupation                   0
Relationship                 0
Race                         0
Sex                          0
Capital gain                 0
Capital loss                 0
Hours per week               0
Country of origin            0
Salary                       0
dtype: int64
```

Pandas 'doesn't see' any '?' charcater. That's why using replace method is useless.

Comment: first improve your description, second try regex with re.sub

Comment: Are you sure that there are no space characters before or after your question marks?